# Nohup and the difference between logout and exit on a remote shell

Tags: unix, shell, nohup

I have access to a remote Linux shell for work purposes. I have kept a python script running in the background using `nohup`.

Now, if I want to exit the session, what is the difference between using `logout` and `exit` commands? Will my script keep running in both of these cases?

Comment: I find it better to use [screen](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gnu_screen/) when I want to make sure console processes live on after I'm gone.

Answer (score 5):

`logout` is an internal command of the shell. So generally the answer is shell-dependent.
From `man bash`:

> `logout` – Exit a login shell.

From `man zsh`:

> `logout [ n ]` – Same as exit, except that it only works in a login shell.

So they're completely the same, but logout will simply refuse to work for non-login shells. What is a login shell can be read in manual pages.

Comment: `exit` is an internal command of the shell, too.

Comment: (Also: I don't see the point of having a exit-like command which only works for login shells. The other way around would be more useful (e.g. "exit only if not in a login shell").)

Answer (score 0):

Try both in your local terminal. If you want use "logout", you need be "login". In your terminal by default you never start the shell with login, so if you want close the terminal you need use "exit". It isn't a "login shell".

In remote ssh shell is indifferent because you're using a "login shell". When you use nohub or similar, you are "detach" the command from the actual shell, so when you close your shell the process doesn't die.